# Asp.net MVC button does not show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, xamarin-studio

I place a button in a `div` tag, and when I run it, I only see the `div` container

```
<div style= "border-style:solid;border-width:1px; padding:5px; background-color:#ffffcc">
    <asp:button ID = "refresh" runat ="server" OnClientClick="reloadPage()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadPage(){
        window.location.reload()    
    }
    </script>
</asp:button>
</div>
```

the `refresh` button is nowhere can be found. Are there anything wrong with my code? I am new to MVC, please give me suggestions.

Comment: Give the button a name/value 'Refresh' sounds good.

Comment: No, I meant add one more property value="Refresh" or text="Refresh" which ever applicable. BTW `asp.net-mvc` doesn't support server control concept `<asp:button>` It's better you re-tag your post.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I added `Text="Refresh"` and it still does not appear. I then added a label within the `div` and the label is shown.

Comment: That's because you are trying to utilize a server control in framework that don't support it follow MichaelLake answer. First of all let us know what framework are you using `asp.net` or `asp.net-mvc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using asp controls in an MVC project -> use an HTML element.

Use a Form

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
</div>
```

Use a Button

```
<div>
    <button onclick="DoSomeJavascript" >Submit</button>
</div>
```

MVC uses Controllers (Code Behind) and Views (Html) to create pages. To send data to or from a page you need to use View Models.

Maybe have a look at this handy guide: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: no wonder `<asp:button>` was not recognized. I thought I chose the aspx engine. Thank you very much.

Comment: actually for me there was an error but I added a pair of brackets `@{using (Html.BeginForm()) {<button> ... </button>} }` now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that you are new to MVC, yet you are trying to define a button from classic ASP.NET, which will not be processed by the Razor view engine used by MVC. Since you are just reloading the page you can do this with regular HTML buttons and Javascript. I'm not reloading the page here in this snippet, but that's irrelevant.

```html
<div style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; padding: 5px; background-color:#ffffcc">
  <button id="refresh" onclick="reloadPage()">
    Refresh Page
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function reloadPage() {
       console.log("Reloaded")
       //Reload page here
      }
    </script>
  </button>
</div>
```

If you run this and click you should see the log message in your Javascript console.